# How do I query (uniquely) the current user's information from Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How do I query the current user's information from Active Directory?

I know that I can access a lot of information about the current user from Windows, such as environment variables and the like. I can get the current user's [username](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085759/712526) and domain, but what do I need to look up the corresponding record in AD?

I especially want to be sure that I can *uniquely identify* the current user in AD, since this script has to deal with a large number of users, and any potential ambiguity could be hard to resolve programmatically. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to do it in PowerShell, assuming you have the ActiveDirectory Module loaded (`ipmo ActiveDirectory`) you can do

```
Get-ADUser ($env:UserName)
```

The logon Username should be unique on the domain and `Get-ADUser` will use the current domain by default

Comment: Nice! Way shorter; but for Windows 7, it does require installing the Remote Server Admin Tools (RSAT) and [turning on](http://its.uiowa.edu/support/article/364) the the PowerShell components, which took me *forever* to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around for a while, I stumbled upon this little [beauty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.current%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), from the .NET API:

```
public static UserPrincipal Current { get; }
```

This has been supported since `.NET 3.5`, so it's perfect for older Windows OSes as well. In PowerShell, it can be used like so:

```
# Load in the Assembly for this stuff
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement") | Out-Null

Function Get-CurrentUser {
    [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::Current
}
```

Comment: This also returns a result for local users, not just AD, so you would need to check `ContextType` of the result. Why not just use `Get-ADUser`?